# KDB/Q How to transpose a table?

Tags: flip, kdb

How do you get the transpose of a table?

Say t:

```
    x          ltCt     poPt     kgAg     xoOt     woWa  yTri zapR    
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    today      41.66    367.69   -662.89  11347.91 30644 -177 19149.92
    yesterday -1570.33 77233.76 -1169.33 11267.63 17079 5623 31069.08
```

and we want t2 to look like:

```
    x     |  today  yesterday
    ltCt  |  41.66  -1570.33
    poPt  |  367.69 77233.76
    ...
```

I wish it was as simple as "flip t" but alas.

Answer (score 4):

So here's the table (not keyed)

```
q)t
x         ltCt poPt kgAg xoOt woWa yTri zapR
--------------------------------------------
today     9    1    8    7    4    4    7
yesterday 2    8    1    2    5    2    8
```

Flip it to turn into a dictionary:

```
q)flip t
x   | today yesterday
ltCt| 9     2
poPt| 1     8
kgAg| 8     1
xoOt| 7     2
woWa| 4     5
yTri| 4     2
zapR| 7     8
```

You'll need some magic to turn it into a proper table:

```
q)flip ft[`x]!flip 1_ value ft:flip t
today yesterday
---------------
9     2
1     8
8     1
7     2
4     5
4     2
7     8
```

**EDIT**

Full transpose

```
q)flip raze[(key 1#ft),value( 1#ft)]!(enlist 1_key ft),flip value 1_ft:flip t
x    today yesterday
--------------------
ltCt 9     2
poPt 1     8
kgAg 8     1
xoOt 7     2
woWa 4     5
yTri 4     2
zapR 7     8
```

Comment: Wow I love q! Thank you user2393012 I owe you a beer

Comment: how do you change this if you have 3 keys in the original table? changing all 1s to 3s gives a length error

Answer (score 3):

"flip" will do the job, just not on a keyed table. Was your table a keyed table by any chance? It looks like it was created using a select-by statement.

In that case try "flip 0!table"