# KDB/Q How to transpose a table with multiple keys?

Tags: kdb

I have a table modeled after the question here:
[KDB/Q How to transpose a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526962/kdb-q-how-to-transpose-a-table)

but my table has an extra 2 keys. What is the general solution to transposing a table with multiple keys? Example table is below:

```
    x         y        z            ltCt     poPt     kgAg     xoOt     woWa  yTri zapR    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    today     setting1 model1       41.66    367.69   -662.89  11347.91 30644 -177 19149.92
    yesterday setting1 model1      -1570.33 77233.76 -1169.33 11267.63 17079 5623 31069.08
    today     setting2 model1       41.66    367.69   -662.89  11347.91 30644 -177 19149.92
    yesterday setting2 model1      -1570.33 77233.76 -1169.33 11267.63 17079 5623 31069.08
    today     setting1 model2       41.66    367.69   -662.89  11347.91 30644 -177 19149.92
    yesterday setting1 model2      -1570.33 77233.76 -1169.33 11267.63 17079 5623 31069.08
...
```

ideal output format:

```
data todaySetting1Model1 yesterdaySetting2Model1 ...
--------------------------------------
ltCt 9                   2
poPt 1                   8
kgAg 8                   1
xoOt 7                   2
woWa 4                   5
yTri 4                   2
zapR 7                   8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a cleaner way to do this but my first thought is that you essentially need to *unpivot* your data and then re-pivot using a different key. So if you take the pivot functionality here (https://code.kx.com/q/kb/pivoting-tables/) and take an unpivot function from Aaron Davies on the k4/kdb archives (13th Feb, 2015):

```
q)show t:([]x:6#`tod`yest;y:6#`set1`set1`set2`set2;z:`m1`m1`m1`m1`m2`m2;ltCt:1+til 6;poPt:10*1+til 6;kgAg:100*1+til 6)
x    y    z  ltCt poPt kgAg
---------------------------
tod  set1 m1 1    10   100
yest set1 m1 2    20   200
tod  set2 m1 3    30   300
yest set2 m1 4    40   400
tod  set1 m2 5    50   500
yest set1 m2 6    60   600

q)unpiv:{[t;k;p;v;f]?[raze?[t;();0b;{x!x}k],'/:(f C){![z;();0b;x!enlist each (),y]}[p]'v xcol't{?[x;();0b;y!y,:()]}/:C:(cols t)except k;enlist(not;(.q.each;.q.all;(null;v)));0b;()]};

q)u:unpiv[t;`x`y`z;1#`data;`v;::];
q)P:exec distinct`$(string[x],'string[y],'string z)from u;
q)exec P#(`$string[x],'string[y],'string z)!v by data:data from u
data| todset1m1 yestset1m1 todset2m1 yestset2m1 todset1m2 yestset1m2
----| --------------------------------------------------------------
kgAg| 100       200        300       400        500       600
ltCt| 1         2          3         4          5         6
poPt| 10        20         30        40         50        60
```

EDIT:

this might be simpler but I don't know if it generalises

```
q){([]data:key x)!value x}flip exec(`$(,'/)string(x;y;z))!([]ltCt;poPt;kgAg)from t
data| todset1m1 yestset1m1 todset2m1 yestset2m1 todset1m2 yestset1m2
----| --------------------------------------------------------------
ltCt| 1         2          3         4          5         6
poPt| 10        20         30        40         50        60
kgAg| 100       200        300       400        500       600
```